# How do I put the text line under an image tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to put the line under the image tag as image below but pseudo-elements doesn't work with `<img>` tag

[image]

Here is my code in codepen:

[Code](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/roGhl)

Hope anyone can help me out. Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you tried border-bottom: solid 1px; ?

Comment: Wrap `img` with another tag. :before, :after pseudo-elements aren't supported for img and input.

Comment: what line are you talking about? the tiny line under the words under the image? or the line that is vertical behind the circles?

Comment: @ntgCleaner I mean the line that is vertical behind circles.

Comment: I was able to fake it using a border on the left elements and padding, but you would have to play around with it to get it centered: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCqDn

Comment: You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try creating a table and inserting the text in the rows beneath the image. You may have to modify text-align to display it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

From [**CSS Selectors Level 3**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content)

> The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements can be used to describe generated content before or after an element's content.

So, `::before` and `::after` will just work on elements which have a content and not work on `input`, `br`, others and also not `img`.

As someone said, wrap your image inside another element, a `div` or whatever you like, and apply it any pseudo-element via CSS.

**Note** If the text is important, non-decorative, you should not use a pseudo-element for that.

Comment: I've wrapped inside a <div>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure css to hack the `<hr>` tag to make it vertical: [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/RPR89/1/)

css

```
.container{
    width: 200px;
}
.blue-box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
hr.vertical{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 330px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    top: 0;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <hr class="vertical"/>
</div>
```

I didn't adjust the z-index so you could see how the `<hr>` tag was positioned.

Comment: You could also do this with any element I guess, and position it behind the other elements.